# JPA 2.x unidirectional one to many relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I would like to know if it is possible to have a one to many jpa 2.x relation between two tables. I am looking for something like this:
(I'd searched a lot with google to find out a similar scenario without success)

```
CUSTOMER
ID   NAME    RELATEDCOLORS
1    John    10
2    Albert  20
3    Maria   10
4    Smith   null

COLORS
ID   FATHERID   COLOR
1    10         Red
2    10         Green
3    10         Blu
4    20         Cyan
```

As you can see each person has a corresponding color. So, both John and Maria colors are red, green and blue. For Albert, the color is Cyan and for Smith there are no colors.

I have tried something like this:

Customer entity

```
....
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private long iId;
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String iName;
@Column(name = "RELATEDCOLORS", nullable = true)
private Long iRelatedColors;
@JoinColumn(name = "FATHERID",referencedColumnName="RELATEDCOLORS", nullable=true)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Colors> iColors;
....
```

Note that I had used "Long iRelatedColors" instead of "long iRelatedColors" because the iRelatedColors attribute can be null

Colors entity

```
....
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private long iId;
@Column(name = "FATHERID", nullable = false)
private long iFatherId;
@Column(name = "COLOR")
private String iColor;
....
```

I do not like to have an attribute of type Customer in the Colors entity

What I need is:

- When a customer is read, then the list iColor must be populated when I invoke the corresponding get... method
- When I update a Customer after a change in the iColors list (e.g: add a new color or delete a color)
  then the colors entity must be updated too.

And I have all that I need only if:

- in the Customer table the RELATEDCOLORS column is filled using a unique number (eg: 10, 20, 30,40 ecc)
- in the Customer table the RELATEDCOLORS column must be always not null, no important if there is the corresponding id in the Colors table.
  If one of the CUSTOMER rows has a null value in the RELATEDCOLORS column, I have during runtime a NullPointerException thrown by hibernate.

Using the data I has show to you does not works and I do not understand why.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your mapping of OneToMany will clearly add a FK to Colors, so if you don't like it then remove that mapping and put OneToOne/ManyToOne and the FK will be in Customer.

Comment: The relationship form Customer > Colors is clearly @ManyToOne so I'm not sure why you are trying to map it as @OneToMany??

Comment: Hi everybody and thanks for your answer.
Neil, could you be more specific, please?

Alan, as you can see from the table data, the relation between Customers > Colors is OneToMany. For example Jhon has the colors red, green and blue

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I can't see anything of the sort. If John should have a collection of colors then there should be a Join table with customer_id color_id. You schema and mappings make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your model contains too much inconsistency and actually is not common at all. What do you do, if `John` gets the colors `Green, Blue and Cyan`? This would mean, that the field `RELATEDCOLORS` cannot be evaluated unless the table `COLORS` gains more data like this, because there still is `Maria` with the colors `Red, Green and Blue`:

```
COLORS
ID   FATHERID   COLOR
1    10         Red
2    10         Green
3    10         Blue
4    20         Cyan
5    30         Green
6    30         Blue
7    30         Cyan
```

This results in a lot of redundant data. Your `Color`-table actually almost looks like a join table, but isn't.
Additional to that, your OneToMany-Relation is an additional join-Table.

Just map your colors as a unidirectional OneToMany as following and get rid of `RELEATEDCOLORS` in Customer and `FATHERID` in Color:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="CUSTOMER_COLORS", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName="iId")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="COLOR_ID", referencedColumnName="iId")})
private List<Color> iColors;
```